# PHP SimpleXML Loop Question

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to do a foreach using xPath. It's working fine and looping through the XML.

My question is can I somehow use a while statement with it. I basically need to find each value of a certain attribute but not for the entire XML. I want the foreach to stop once it hits a certain attribute.

Example:

```
<InvoiceRet>

    <TxnID>23827-1290392819</TxnID>
    <TimeCreated>2010-11-21T21:26:59-05:00</TimeCreated>

        <InvoiceLineRet>
            <TxnLineID>23829-1290392819</TxnLineID>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

        <InvoiceLineRet>
            <TxnLineID>2382A-1290392819</TxnLineID>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

</InvoiceRet>

<InvoiceRet>

    <TxnID>2382F-1290392820</TxnID>

        <InvoiceLineRet>
            <TxnLineID>2382B-1290392819</TxnLineID>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

                    <InvoiceLineRet>
            <TxnLineID>2382B-1290392819</TxnLineID>
        </InvoiceLineRet>

</InvoiceRet>
```

I basically need to loop through the first set of  but not the second set. So I was hoping that I can stop the loop when it hits the second .

The problem is I have no idea how to do it.

Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: what elements are you trying to loop over? the <InvoiceLineRet />'s in the first <InvoiceRet /> ??

Comment: There is no attributes in the shown XML. Please clarify the question.

Comment: Sorry, I was not that clear. I need to get all of the <InvoiceLineRet> in each of the <InvoiceRet> separately. All of the <InvoiceLineRet> in the first one need to be inserted into SQL with a matching ID from the first set and then the second set need to match that second set. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only looking to get the first one all the time then, you could just break the loob after getting the first one.

```
foreach ($TxnID as $t){
     echo $t;
     break;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not that clear. I need to get all of the <InvoiceLineRet> in each of the <InvoiceRet> separately. All of the <InvoiceLineRet> in the first one need to be inserted into SQL with a matching ID from the first set and then the second set need to match that second set. Thanks